# Adding the CAS Authentication Filter to my web xml prevents my webapp from starting

Tags: java, tomcat, cas

I am trying a very basic test of the java CAS client using the various instructions available on the web.

I have determined that my webapp (in tomcat) will start with every CAS filter configured except the first one, the CAS Authentication Filter.

There is no output to any log file that I can find.

Can anybody point me to troubleshooting ideas - I think I have tried everything :)

-Bill

Answer (score 0):

A couple things got this working for me:

1: setting up logging.properties so that the SEVERE: filterStart error would be output - but it is output to localhost.out not to catalina.out in my case

2: I set up the serverName as a context-param instead of an init-param

3: Examples on the web don't mention that you need slf4j support. I included that jar from the 3.3.3 maven build.